# How do I make hover attributes permanent? [CSS]

Tags: css, hover, liquid

I will be using images as it may be hard to understand otherwise. We have these social icons in the footer of our site that have a lovely hover state, however, I can't seem to replicate it without the hover.

Facebook Icon: Hover Inactive:

[image: Facebook Icon: Hover Inactive]

Facebook Icon: Hover Active:

[image: Facebook Icon: Hover Active]

I would like to replicate the hover style without actually hovering. HTML:

```
<li class="facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" title="Facebook">
        <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and the css:

```
.social li.facebook a:hover {
  background-color: #325c94;
}
.social li.facebook a:hover * {
  color:#fff !important;
}
```

When removing the hover state from the css the following happens:

Facebook Icon: Remove Hover:

[image: Facebook Icon: Remove Hover]

I would have expected it to look like the active hover state but it doesn't, any input regarding my problem would be very much appreciated. Thank you.
- Leon

Comment: what do you mean by without hovering

Comment: can you show us the circle around icon css

Comment: Biswajit - Just having the style of the hover element without the hover element


לבני מלכה - Using Font Awesome 4.7. 


Kindly, alyson_216 has shown me the correct way. I had accidentally removed a little more than just the psuedo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the :hover pseudo class and put the styling on anchor tag to show the style.

```
.social li.facebook a{
   color:#fff !important;
 }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I can see where I was going wrong now.

I was removing 'a:hover' <-- silly me
and not just the psuedo class ':hover'. Didn't even realise.

Answer (score 0):

add border-radius 50% to it

```
.social li.facebook a:hover {
  background-color: #325c94;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```